# Composite data type missing value when returned from function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.2, composite-types

I have a function returning a `setof` a composite data type. When I run the function, only one of the two columns defined in the composite data type has data in it. When troubleshooting the problem I did a `RAISE NOTICE` on the composite data type and it has data in the column that is missing data in the result set. I tested both before and after the `RETURN NEXT`. I am using PostgreSQL 9.2.
Any idea why the result set is missing the data?

```
CREATE TYPE map_data AS (lid uuid, tile_ids uuid [] );

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_map_data(mid_val uuid) RETURNS SETOF map_data AS $$
DECLARE
    j uuid;
    b uuid;
    m map_data%rowtype;
    tid uuid []; --tile ids
BEGIN
FOR j IN
    SELECT lid FROM map_layers WHERE "mid" = mid_val
LOOP
    FOREACH b IN ARRAY (SELECT tiles FROM layer_tiles WHERE lid = j) 
    LOOP
        tid := array_append(tid,b);
    END LOOP;
    SELECT j, tid INTO m;
    RETURN NEXT m;
    tid := '{}'; --clear the array.
END LOOP;
RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: How do you *call* the function exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you call the function like this:

```
SELECT * FROM get_map_data( ... );
```

And not like this:

```
SELECT get_map_data( ... );
```

Or you get the whole composite type as a single column.

#### Possible explanation

[**UUIDs** can be written with enclosing curly braces (`{}`) in text representation.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-uuid.html) This happens to match the syntax for literal array constants, which use the same braces. This literal can be cast to `uuid` and `uuid[]` alike:

```
'{a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11}'
```

Which might introduce ambiguity. Just speculating, but I could imagine that some clients get confused with the syntax rules and concatenate element and array to a single datum.

Even this [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/87893/9) runs into a JDBC error! (While the same works with integer data.)

#### Better alternative

Either way, there is a lot of **pointless effort** in your function. Looping, unnesting and re-building arrays, ...
The whole shebang can be replaced with this simple and much faster query:

```
SELECT m.lid, tiles
FROM   map_layers  m
JOIN   layer_tiles l USING (lid)
WHERE  m.mid = $mid_val;
```

Wrap it into an SQL function if needed:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_map_data(_mid_val uuid)
  RETURNS SETOF map_data AS
$func$
SELECT m.lid, l.tiles
FROM   map_layers  m
JOIN   layer_tiles l USING (lid)
WHERE  m.mid = $1
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```